# windows forms is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

unable to integrate Forms authentication in my application. always redirecting to login page . after login its redirecting to login page again . in url its showing - http://localhost:1186/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fIndex.aspx

**web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">              
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**code behind**
login page button click event

```
objAmin.AdminLoginId = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
objAmin.Password = txtPasssword.Text.Trim();
DataSet dsAdminLoginDetail = objAmin.GetAdminLoginDetails();              
DataRowCollection drc = dsAdminLoginDetail.Tables[0].Rows;
if (drc.Count > 0)
{
   lblError.Visible = false;
   DataRow dr = drc[0];             
   Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");    
}
```

Comment: Not enough info, see [ask]

Comment: You are never setting your forms auth cookie: FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, true); Becuase of that anywhere you try to go will redirect you back to the login page, as it should.

Comment: thanks i got it...@StephenBrickner